# How can I compile a C# visual studio project without the default DLL file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'll just cut straight to the point.

I am making a compiler in C#, and creating it using visual studio. When I build my compiler to an executable, it also builds a "runtime" dll, how can I force visual studio to only build the executable without the dll?
(this is a .net core project)

hypec.csproj

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

solution

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
# Visual Studio Version 16
VisualStudioVersion = 16.0.29509.3
MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 10.0.40219.1
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "hype", "hype.csproj", "{4653DC57-ACFF-419D-A57C-CEF0B5ECA174}"
EndProject
Global
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
        Release|Any CPU = Release|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
        {4653DC57-ACFF-419D-A57C-CEF0B5ECA174}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {4653DC57-ACFF-419D-A57C-CEF0B5ECA174}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {4653DC57-ACFF-419D-A57C-CEF0B5ECA174}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {4653DC57-ACFF-419D-A57C-CEF0B5ECA174}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
        HideSolutionNode = FALSE
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ExtensibilityGlobals) = postSolution
        SolutionGuid = {8D8BF52E-5BB5-4F40-8365-9A6C3EBD042E}
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214870/discussion-on-question-by-jeremy-pace-how-can-i-compile-a-c-visual-studio-proje).

Comment: @CoyMeeks just easy deployment, I guess. Now I feel like an idiot because I didn't think about why dlls were bad in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the reference here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-core-3-0

To publish a single-file executable, set the PublishSingleFile in your project or on the command line with the dotnet publish command:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <RuntimeIdentifier>win10-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
  <PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>
</PropertyGroup>
```

OR

```
dotnet publish -r win10-x64 -p:PublishSingleFile=true
```